# JMX MBeans and Azure Application Insights

Tags: java, azure, jmx, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I've just started using Azure for a large Java project, and I have two questions about application layer monitoring.  I know that it's possible for App Insights/Monitor to ingest metrics from Java apps that are exposed via JMX MBeans (an example is shown in http://joe.blog.freemansoft.com/2015/12/enabling-microsoft-application-insight.html).  Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible for an Azure Function written in Java to output application-layer metrics to JMX MBeans, which can then be consumed by Azure Monitor/Application Insights?
2. We have a COTS 3rd party Java app which we're running in a container which can output application layer metrics via JMX MBean.  Is there a way to get Azure Monitor/Application Insights to ingest these metrics?

Comment: Hey, by any chance, were you able to make this work?